# Layered attribute navigation hiding when all active

Tags: magento-1.9, php, catalog, layered-navigation

I'm having an issue with my Magento code which is used to modify the layout of the left layered navigation. I'm looking to have all items visible in the navigation even if they are currently active, however; when they are all active, the menu disappears. Did I incorrectly set it up or is there a simple mistake I have made?

### [image: 1 Chosen Attribute:] [image: 2 Chosen Attributes:]

Here is my code:

State.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation state
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State
 */
?>
<?php
$_filters = $this->getActiveFilters();
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
?>
<?php if(!empty($_filters)): ?>
<div class="currently">
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
        <?php
        $_rendered = false;
        foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
            $_renderer = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
            if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_filter)):
                $_renderer->setFilter($_filter);
                echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                $_rendered = true;
                break;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Filter.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for filter items block
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter
 */
$count = 0;
?>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item):
    $count++;
    ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
        <?
        $_filters = $this->getActiveFilters();
        ?>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion<? echo $count ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading<? echo $count ?>">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<? echo $count ?>" href="#collapse<? echo $count ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<? $count ?>">
                            <dt><?php echo $this->__($_item->getName()) ?></dt>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse<? echo $count ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<? echo $count ?>">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <dd>
                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>'"/>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                            </a>
                        </dd>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?
$_appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
foreach ($_appliedFilters as $_item) {
    ?>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion<? echo $count ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading<? echo $count ?>">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<? echo $count ?>" href="#collapse<? echo $count ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<? $count ?>">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->__($_item->getName()) ?></dt>
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse<? echo $count ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<? echo $count ?>">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <dd>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getRemoveUrl()) ?>'"/>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getRemoveUrl()) ?>">
                            <?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
                        </a>
                    </dd>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

View.phtml

```
    <?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block block-layered-nav">
        <div class="block-title">
            <h3>Refine By:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content refinements">
            <?php echo $this->getStateHtml(); ?>

            <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
                <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                    <dd>
                        <section id="nav-sidebox">
                            <?php
                            $_filters = $this->getFilters();
                            $_appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
                            $count = 0;
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()):  ?>
                                    <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <? $count = $count + 1; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?
                            if ($count == 0){
                                foreach ($_appliedFilters as $_filter): ?>
                                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()):  ?>
                                    <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <? $count = $count + 1; ?>
                                <? endforeach; ?> <?
                            }
                            ?>
                        </section>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hi  frinds images cant't display any thing

Comment: What menu is hiding?? I cannot access your image, Sice I am accessing thru proxy.  Upload and show ur screens here. http://photobucket.com/learn/upload

Comment: Images updated. Not sure why they weren't accessible

Comment: Sorry.. I still cannot access.  .I am using thru a proxy... Upload image in photobucket.  I can access nly photobucket.

Comment: Are u hiding .refinements when u click???

Comment: No, when i click i simply have the refinement checkbox ticked. When i click all of them the box disappears, This is abnormal.

Comment: Is your dev site available online? From the images above it is not clear what behavior is going on. As I understood, when you checking one checkbox it works normal, but when you checking all of them, they disappear, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct Shariff, is that all you need to know?

Comment: Here is the development site: https://valeroux.com/temp/bags.html . I've also noticed they duplicate...

Comment: I've just seen your website. But I don't understand your question very well. You said: "I'm looking to have all items visible in the navigation even if they are currently active, however". There are multiple material types and only one appears?

Comment: Hi Oliver K, did you follow any particular procedure to create the code ? I reckon you should check Inchoo guide to keep all filters visible when filtering via layered navigation and adapt their solution to your custom theme: http://inchoo.net/magento/layered-navigation-but-not-quite/

Answer (score 1):

See As per **Magento** Standard How the **Layered Navigation** will be display.

1. Layered Navigation will display Based on the Product listing.
2. Layered Navigation contain the Filterable option which the generally
   the product Attributes. So that will be display in layered
   navigation.
3. General logic Layered Navigation is Depended on the Product Listing.

**In sort you can not display only Layered Navigation with your Products.**

Answer (score 1):

In state.phtml change this

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
```

to this

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers');
```